# Computer sequence

Tags: sequence

You have created a computer, but it is not working, only printing sets of 4 characters in a sequence. If you can predict the next 3 sets, then you can restart the computer and set it up so you can actually use it. The computer will print out 1 more set every day at a random time.

Sequence:

3826
³¸²¶
sxrv
óøòö
no_output
no_output
KDJN
no_output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, got a new answer..

It appears that ...

> the first number in each set is just the computer counting by 1s, but you've mixed up the least significant bit with the most significant bit..

That is the first number in each set is ...

> '3' --> decimal 51 --> binary 00110011
>  '³' --> decimal 179 --> binary 10110011
>  's' --> decimal 115 --> binary 01110011
>  etc..

So the next three sets (after the final no_output that was added to the question later) will start with ...

> binary 00101011 --> decimal 43 --> '+'
>  binary 10101011 --> decimal 171 --> '«'
>  binary 01101011 --> decimal 107 --> 'k'

Therefore the next three patterns are:

> +$*.
>  «¤ª®
>  kdjn

Hope I did those conversions right..  I feel better about this answer than my previous one.

Comment: Well done, but I think you did your conversions incorrectly. This is what I got:   +$*.    «¤ª®    kdjn

Comment: Oops, you're right - I messed up the second character in my haste due to an invalid assumption..  I'll edit the answer so its correct..  Thanks for the puzzle!

Comment: You’re welcome 

Answer (score 1):

I think the next three are:

> ËÄÊÎ
>  no_output
>  ċĄĊĎ

because

> the characters are based on the Unicode table, where each set of 4 is val, val+5, val-1, val+3
>  and patterns fluctuate between adding 128 then subtracting 64.

so

> Using the decimal values for the codes the first 4 patterns are:
> 51 56 50 54 (51, 51+5, 51-1, 51+3)
> 179 184 178 182 (51+128, 51+128+5, 51+128-1, 51+128+3)
> 115 120 114 118 (179-64, 179-64+5, 179-64-1, 179-64+3)
> 243 248 242 246 (115+128, 115+128+5, 115+128-1, 115+128+3)
> and the pattern continues..

Comment: good try, but unfortunately it's incorrect. You were right with the ascii thing though

Comment: argh, yeah I figured it wasn't quite what you were looking for.. I'm out of time for now, but the numbers involved in the patterns hints strongly at binary representation, so that would be my next investigation..

Comment: You’re on the right track!